# why kotlin multiplatform don't execute and export iOS framework?

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-native, kotlin-multiplatform

I started develop kotlin multiplatform and I developed a simple lib for test. I can exported `.jar` file for android but I can't export `.framework` file for iOS.
I reviewed other project but I didn't find my issue.

my `Gradle` script for lib is:

```
apply plugin: 'kotlin-multiplatform'

kotlin {
targets {
    final def iOSTarget = 
    System.getenv('SDK_NAME')?.startsWith("iphoneos") \
                          ? presets.iosArm64 : presets.iosX64

    fromPreset(iOSTarget, 'iOS') {
        compilations.main.outputKinds('FRAMEWORK')
    }

    fromPreset(presets.jvm, 'android')
}

sourceSets {
    core.dependencies {
        api 'org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-common'
    }

    android.dependencies {
        api 'org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib'
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you added the task to build the actual framework? If not, try adding this code at the end of your `build.gradle` file:

```
task packForXCode(type: Sync) {
    final File frameworkDir = new File(buildDir, "xcode-frameworks")
    final String mode = project.findProperty("XCODE_CONFIGURATION")?.toUpperCase() ?: 'DEBUG'

    inputs.property "mode", mode
    dependsOn kotlin.targets.iOS.compilations.main.linkTaskName("FRAMEWORK", mode)

    from { kotlin.targets.iOS.compilations.main.getBinary("FRAMEWORK", mode).parentFile }
    into frameworkDir

    doLast {
        new File(frameworkDir, 'gradlew').with {
            text = "#!/bin/bash\nexport 'JAVA_HOME=${System.getProperty("java.home")}'\ncd '${rootProject.rootDir}'\n./gradlew \$@\n"
            setExecutable(true)
        }
    }
}

tasks.build.dependsOn packForXCode
```

The iOS framework will be available on the `build/xcode-frameworks` directory of your library.

You'll have to configure also your Xcode project to use the framework. For further details you can read [Setting up Framework Dependency in Xcode](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/tutorials/native/mpp-ios-android.html#setting-up-framework-dependency-in-xcode).

Comment: no error message for this. just don't any exports for iOS.

Comment: @AlirezaTarazani. No error message? I doubt it but make sure the task is actually executed.

Comment: After adding `packForXCode`, are you running `./gradlew :common:packForXCode` (assuming your `build.gradle` is in a directory called `common`). I'm able to get it working using the code posted here and running this command.

Comment: I'm getting "Task with path 'linkMainDebugFrameworkIOS' not found in project" when running ./gradlew :shared:packForXCode. Any hints?

Comment: Solved my own problem!: Framework name was different in packForXCode and gradle.

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean by "exporting a framework"? Are you going to use it from another Gradle project or from XCode or from something else?

P.S. Sorry for asking in answers: just have no enough reputation to leave a comment. So I think it would be more convenient to discuss you problem in issues at [GitHub](https://github.com/JetBrains/kotlin-native).